# How can I only pull back the latest result in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, iteration

I'm struggling to find out how to only return the latest iteration of the `claimtid` in the result set. I'm using this query:

```
SELECT
   claimid, paiddate
   CASE
      WHEN actid = '119' THEN 'Channel Exception'
      WHEN actid = '127' THEN 'Rejected'
      WHEN actid = '128' THEN 'Accepted'
      WHEN actid = '130' THEN 'Adjustment Complete'
      WHEN actid = '133' THEN 'Channel Ready'
   END AS [Status]
FROM
    Encounter
WHERE 
    claimtid LIKE '173225AR0%' OR claimtid LIKE '197565GL0%' OR 
    claimtid LIKE '293215QW0%' OR claimtid LIKE
ORDER BY 
    claimtid
```

This query returns the following result:

```
 |claimtid  |paiddt    |Status             |
-+----------+----------+-------------------+
1|173225AR00|2017-03-01|Adjustment Complete|
2|173225AR01|2017-04-11|Accepted           |
3|197565GL00|2017-03-17|Accepted           |
4|197565GL01|2017-03-19|Adjustment Complete|
5|197565GL02|2017-04-01|Rejected           |
6|293215QW00|2017-04-19|Adjustment Complete|
7|293215QW01|2017-04-23|Accepted           |
```

I'm not sure what I can add to my query so that the results will only bring back lines 2, 5, and 7. My actual query contains produces more rows in the result.

This is only an example, but is accurate to the situation. I'll need to pull back more than 3 rows, but it needs to be the latest iteration.

Each additional iteration makes the last number in the claimtid go up by one. I won't know how many iterations there are of each claimtid.

Comment: What do you mean by latest iteration? What is different in lines 2, 5 and 7?

Comment: @Lamar....So in rows 1-2 the claimtid is the same except for the last number at the end of the id. In Row one that last two digits of claimtid are 00 and in row two the last two digits of claimtid is 01. So, the latest iteration of that claim is the one ending in 01. Same for row 5 because the latest iteration of that claimtid is 02.

Comment: Oh, now I see. can you separate the last part of the claimtid into a separate field? That would make your life much easier.

Comment: @Lamar...you're saying to separate the last two characters into their own column by selecting a substring of the claimtid and filter based on that column?

Comment: Actually I meant saving it in a different column altogether. But yet you can check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but I am not sure of the performance penalty for using a string for claimtid as in your case:

```
SELECT claimid, paiddate
FROM
Encounter
WHERE claimtid IN (
    SELECT MAX(paiddt), claimtid  
    FROM Encounter
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING (claimtid, 6, 8)
) t
```

Assuming you can count on the paiddate field to know the most recent record.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't separate the two fields of the claim ID into separate columns of the data table itself, you can pull them apart in a query, to allow you to use the `max()` aggregate to find the largest value of the second field.

```
select
    claim,
    paiddate,
    CASE
        WHEN actid = '119' THEN 'Channel Exception'
        WHEN actid = '127' THEN 'Rejected'
        WHEN actid = '128' THEN 'Accepted'
        WHEN actid = '130' THEN 'Adjustment Complete'
        WHEN actid = '133' THEN 'Channel Ready'
        END AS [Status]
from
    (
        select
            left(claimid, 6) as claim,
            max(right(claimid,4)) as seq,
        from
            Encounter
        group by
            left(claimid, 6)
    ) as ms
    inner join Encounter as e
        on e.claimid = ms.claim + ms.seq;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ClaimData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #ClaimData;

CREATE TABLE #ClaimData (
    RN INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    claimtid CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    paiddt DATE NOT NULL,
    [Status] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #ClaimData (claimtid, paiddt, Status) VALUES

    ('173225AR00', '2017-03-01', 'Adjustment Complete'),
    ('173225AR01', '2017-04-11', 'Accepted'),
    ('197565GL00', '2017-03-17', 'Accepted'),
    ('197565GL01', '2017-03-19', 'Adjustment Complete'),
    ('197565GL02', '2017-04-01', 'Rejected'),
    ('293215QW00', '2017-04-19', 'Adjustment Complete'),
    ('293215QW01', '2017-04-23', 'Accepted');

--SELECT * FROM #ClaimData cd;

--=========================================================

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
    cd.RN, cd.claimtid, cd.paiddt, cd.Status
FROM
    #ClaimData cd
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (SUBSTRING(cd.claimtid, 1, 6), SUBSTRING(cd.claimtid, 7, 4)) ) sc (Claim_1, Claim_2)
ORDER BY 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sc.Claim_1 ORDER BY sc.Claim_2 DESC);
```

Results...

```
RN          claimtid   paiddt     Status
----------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
2           173225AR01 2017-04-11 Accepted
5           197565GL02 2017-04-01 Rejected
7           293215QW01 2017-04-23 Accepted
```

Edit...
A slightly better performing solution that produces the same results...

```
SELECT 
    RN = CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(bv.BinaryValue), 39, 4) AS INT),
    claimtid = CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(bv.BinaryValue), 1, 10) AS CHAR(10)),
    paiddt = CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(bv.BinaryValue), 11, 8) AS DATE),
    Status = CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(bv.BinaryValue), 19, 20) AS VARCHAR(20))
FROM
    #ClaimData cd
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CAST(cd.claimtid AS BINARY(10)) + CAST(cd.paiddt AS BINARY(8)) + CAST(cd.Status AS BINARY(20)) + CAST(cd.RN AS BINARY(4))) ) bv (BinaryValue)
GROUP BY 
    SUBSTRING(cd.claimtid, 1, 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming you can't have a early claimtid with a later paiddt:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ClaimData') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #ClaimData

CREATE TABLE #ClaimData (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    , claimtid CHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , paiddt DATE NOT NULL
    , [Status] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
)
INSERT #ClaimData (claimtid, paiddt, Status) VALUES

    ('173225AR00', '2017-03-01', 'Adjustment Complete')
    ,('173225AR01', '2017-04-11', 'Accepted')
    ,('197565GL00', '2017-03-17', 'Accepted')
    ,('197565GL01', '2017-03-19', 'Adjustment Complete')
    ,('197565GL02', '2017-04-01', 'Rejected')
    ,('293215QW00', '2017-04-19', 'Adjustment Complete')
    ,('293215QW01', '2017-04-23', 'Accepted')

SELECT
    ID
    , x.claimtid
    , x.paiddt
    , x.Status
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(Claimtid, LEN(Claimtid) - 2) ORDER BY paiddt DESC) RN
        , *
    FROM #ClaimData
) x
WHERE x.RN = 1
```

Otherwise change `RN` to `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(Claimtid, LEN(Claimtid) - 2) ORDER BY RIGHT(Claimtid, 2) DESC) RN`